# jQuery -- Variable string printed as one word

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am writing some jquery that will grab an array of xml files. It then will loop through these and parse through them to show them on the page. I have this working but one thing I would like to do if before it lists out the contents, I want it to print the name of the file. Here is the code I have.

```
$.get('inc/getMenuFiles.php', function(data) {
    var catSplit = data.split(",");
    var menuitems = $('.menuitems');
    menuitems.empty();

    for (i=2; i<catSplit.length; i++) {

        url = "inc/menulists/" +catSplit[i].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/]/g, '');
        catName = catSplit[i].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/.xml/g, '').replace(/]/g, '');

        menuitems.append(catName);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    var name =  $(this).find('name').text();
                    var price = $(this).find('price').text();
                    menuitems.append(name + " - $" +price + "<br />");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is not valid but if I do this it works

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                async: true,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                        var price = $(this).find('price').text();
                        menuitems.append(name + " - $" +price + "<br />");
                    });
                }
            }).delay();
```

So I guess I just need to properly add a delay, after that ajax call

Comment: That name of the file you mention: how different it is from `catName`?

Comment: Your question is about printing the variable string but your requirements is about printing the file name. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Basically menuitems.append(catName); is working but it is printing all the file names as one string. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about: http://twitpic.com/9y6xwz

Comment: @raina77ow - I just remove the .xml and " from it, that is all that variable is doing

Comment: Do you mean "in one **line**", instead of *string*?

Comment: Now I find this interesting. This is invalid but if I add a .delay to the ajax call it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your Ajax callbacks won't execute until the current execution path finishes. To get around this you can wait until inside your ajax callback to append catName. This should work:

```
$.get('inc/getMenuFiles.php', function(data) {
    var catSplit = data.split(",");
    var menuitems = $('.menuitems');
    menuitems.empty();

    for (i=2; i<catSplit.length; i++) {

        url = "inc/menulists/" +catSplit[i].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/]/g, '');
        catName = catSplit[i].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/.xml/g, '').replace(/]/g, '');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: (function(catName){
                return function(xml) {
                    menuitems.append(catName);

                    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                        var name =  $(this).find('name').text();
                        var price = $(this).find('price').text();
                        menuitems.append(name + " - $" +price + "<br />");
                    });
                }
            })(catName)
        });
    }
});
```

You still (just like in your original code) have no guarantee on the order your requests could complete, so sometimes `appetizers.xml` and `beer.xml` will load in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your for-loop is faster than the AJAX call. Remember that the first **A** in *AJAX* stands fro *asynchronous*.  Picture this...

> You're at the beginning of your for-loop. You take take the first `catName`, and append it to `menuitems`. Then you fire up an AJAX call to fetch the `name` and `price` of each `item` in the `catName`. Meanwhile, the AJAX request hasn't responded yet, so we move one to the second `catName`, fire up another AJAX request. The first one isn't done, and we just fired a second request; so now we have 2 AJAX responses pending. In the meantime, we move on the third `catName`.
>
> *And so on, and so forth...*

**Solutions**

1. Set the [`async`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property in your inner AJAX call to `false`. This will make the for-loop pause until the request is completed.
2. ** **PREFERRED **** Make your AJAX calls before the for-loop, store the response somewhere (in an array perhaps), than run your for-loop using this array.

Comment: I thought async was set to true by default? I added it anyways and still same result.

Comment: 1) The speed of the for loop is irrelevant. Even if it took 10 days to  execute the for loop the callback function for the first request won't execute until the for loop is done. 2) You mean set `async` to `false`, and that is a very bad solution.

Comment: Here is a demonstration of how asynchronous Javascript is independant of the speed of the for loop: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Etkkk/

Comment: @That's half fixed. If you remove the part about it happening because the for loop is faster and change it to something along the lines of "the for loop finishes executing before the first callback function executes" (Even if the AJAX request has completed) I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @ascii-lime, you may be right about using `async: false` being a bad solution (that's why I offered an alternative), but you are wrong about speed not being issue. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JVxrV/

Comment: *"________ finishes ________ before ________" is* about speed.

Comment: @AymanSafadi No that example is incomplete because you don't show that the AJAX calls respond first if the for loop is slower than them. The opposite is actually true: If you make your for loop slower you'll see that the AJAX callbacks are still called after. For example if you do nothing for 1 second each iteration of the loop the whole loop will take 10 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/JVxrV/1/ You can very with something like Chrome Developer Tools Network tab that all the requests are responding before the loop finishes, but they're callbacks execute after the loop finishes.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded and every thread finishes before another thread can start.

Comment: ok so at the end of the loop I added <$(this).delay();> and the issue is resolved. Is this a bad solution?

Comment: You can also use `console.log` to see this better since `append` doesn't do anything until the whole loop finishes either: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/JVxrV/3/. If you open the console while running that JSFiddle you can see the time when each iteration starts and when each of the callback are called.

Comment: @jrock2004, `delay()` *is* a bad solution because you can't guarantee that the request will take less time than the `$.delay` will give you. For example, if the server is unusually slow that day, `$.delay()` is won't be enough. I'd go with my second solution.

Comment: @ascii-lime: While JavaScript *is* single-threaded, an asynchronous HTTP request (*XMLHttpRequest* to be exact) is *not* one of these threads, hence the *asynchronous* part. I've updated my jsFiddle to demonstrate this point: http://jsfiddle.net/JVxrV/5/

Comment: You loop demonstrates my point perfectly. The callback function for a request is a Javascript thread and will never execute until the loop finishes. No matter how much longer you make your loop the whole loop will always finish before the first callback function executes.

Comment: @AymanSafadi Haha now I feel bad for downvoting all the sudden. You did correct the `async` false part and I was in a pretty grumpy mood yesterday.

Comment: @ascii-lime No worries. I'll take learning something over my ego any day!